# Mostrar datos de tablas diferentes en mysql

Tags: php, mysql

tengo un problema al querer mostrar datos de tablas diferentes veran, estoy realizando un inventario de productos, mis tablas son la siguientes:

[image: Venta y su respectivo detalle, así como pedido y detalle de pedido]

Quiero que mi consulta muestre la ultima venta y el ultimo pedido de los productos, actualmente mi consulta es esta:

```
SELECT pedido.id,MAX(fecha_ped) AS Ultima_Entrada,model,descr,ser,cantidad,det_ped.total,
(SELECT venta.id,MAX(fecha_vta) AS Ultima_Salida,modelo_vta,desc_vta,serie_vta,cantidad_det,det_vta.total)
FROM pedido INNER JOIN det_ped ON(pedido.id=det_ped.id_ped), venta INNER JOIN det_vta ON(venta.id=det_vta.id_vta)
WHERE modelo_vta=model AND ser=serie_vta AND descr=desc_vta ORDER BY venta.id,pedido.id;
```

pero me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
Error Code: 1241
```

Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tambien probe con `UNION`, pero no me agrupa los productos como quiero, el resultado que busco es algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

agrupado.

La consulta de union me muestra mas o menos lo que quiero pero no agrupado:

```
SELECT pedido.id,MAX(fecha_ped) AS Ultima_Entrada,model,descr,ser,cantidad,det_ped.total,pedido.estatus FROM pedido INNER JOIN
```

det_ped ON(pedido.id=det_ped.id_ped) GROUP BY model,descr,ser
UNION 
SELECT venta.id,MAX(fecha_vta) AS Ultima_Salida,modelo_vta,desc_vta,serie_vta,cantidad_det,total,estatus FROM venta INNER JOIN
det_vta ON(venta.id=det_vta.id_vta) GROUP BY modelo_vta,serie_vta,desc_vta;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si se preguntan porque tengo modelo, descripcion y serie en los detalles de las tablas es debido a que los productos tienen numero de serie.

Comment: Revisa la sintaxis en el select que te está dando error. En la subconsulta (SELECT venta.id,MAX(fecha_vta) AS Ultima_Salida,modelo_vta,desc_vta,serie_vta,cantidad_det,det_vta.total) no hay un FROM, puede que eso te esté generando el error. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT pedido.id,MAX(fecha_ped) AS Ultima_Entrada,model,descr,ser,cantidad,det_ped.total,
(SELECT venta.id,MAX(fecha_vta) AS Ultima_Salida,modelo_vta,desc_vta,serie_vta,cantidad_det,det_vta.total)
FROM pedido INNER JOIN det_ped ON(pedido.id=det_ped.id_ped) INNER JOIN venta det_vta ON(venta.id=det_vta.id_vta)
WHERE modelo_vta=model AND ser=serie_vta AND descr=desc_vta ORDER BY venta.id,pedido.id;

así debería quedar.